# "Их было тысяча человек". Как разобрать по членам предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология, согласование, числительные, члены-предложения

- Как разобрать по членам это предложение и почему встречается разное согласование глагола и подлежащего?

Из Нац. корпуса:
*На то **была** тысяча причин.

У Паши **была** тысяча шансов*.
*Ведь у меня **было** тысяча триста франков!

Всего защитников Осы **было** тысяча человек*.

На сайте *лицей.нет* есть правило:

> Согласование по роду есть и при числительном тысяча, миллион, миллиард.
>   *Явилась тысяча человек.*

- Или в безличном предложении для глагола **было** возможно употребление без согласования рода?

Comment: При перечислении после двоеточия следует ставить тчк/зпт. Почему «нац. корпус» со строчной? Это не название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) О согласовании**

Розенталь http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

При словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард сказуемое **обычно согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными** (в роде и числе), например: Тысяча книг поступила в школьную библиотеку; Миллион демонстрантов заполнил площади и улицы столицы.

Из книги "Практическая стилистика" (2012): **Возможно и согласование по смыслу**: Тысяча добровольцев откликнулись на беду.

Итак, **допускаются варианты согласования,** которые нужно выбирать в зависимости от разных факторов (позиция относительно сказуемого, одуш. сущ,, неодуш. сущ. и др.

**Выбор ед. числа или мн. числа** —  обычная проблема для любых числительных, а тысяча — это грамматическое существительное, которое может образовывать счетный оборот как обычное числительное (отсюда еще один вариант).

2) И поводу **грамматического разбора**: счетный оборот — это единый член предложения, который является подлежащим: У него  была/было **тысяча рублей**. Их было **тысяча человек** (предложения двусоставное).